# Accidental colonists on Mars survive being stranded because Mars plants grow and provide the necessities of life

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I hate myself for not recalling this, but...  I thought it might be by Brin, but I checked in *The River of Time* and *Otherness* and didn't find it.  I would have read it sometime after 1995-ish, I believe.

I don't remember the circumstances at all, but an exploration mission to Mars is stranded for some reason.  There is political upheaval on Earth, and nobody comes for them in the next synod either.

Eventually, another mission is sent to Mars, and they go to the original landing site to see what happened, only everyone is still alive (and they have kids).  Apparently, the local changes caused by their encampment (traces of gases leaked by the airlock, local heating of the soil from the building, etc.) triggered Martian life to start up.

Said Martian life was originally things like plants that had little berry-like clusters of oxygen tanks and plants that produced water.  More complex organisms followed, including some that produce transparent air-tight fabric that can be wrapped around someone to produce a very simple space suit.

I recall a scene where one of the astronauts is first investigating the oxygen berries, and not knowing what it is, drills into it.  It disappears with a bang, ricochets around the lab, and when they pick it up it is intensely cold.

The story ends with one of the characters noting the increasingly complex Martian life, and thinking that now they're waiting for a Martian to show up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

["In the Hall of the Martian Kings"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50199), a novella by [John Varley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Varley_%28author%29), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, February 1977](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61100+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v052n02_1977-02/page/n5/mode/2up). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?50199).

The explorers are stranded on Mars because a mishap on the ground has killed the only people who knew how to pilot the lander. Martian spores have responded to local changes in the environment caused by the landing:

> "You've heard of the long-period Martian seasonal theories? Well, part of it is more than a theory. The combination of the Martian polar inclination, the processional cycle, and the eccentricity of the orbit produces seasons that are about twelve thousand years
> long. We're in the middle of winter, though we landed in the nominal 'summer.' It's been theorized that if there were any Martian life it would have adapted to these longer cycles. It hibernates in spores during the cold cycle, when the water and carbon dioxide freeze out at the poles, then comes out when enough ice melts to permit biological processes. We seem to have fooled these plants; they thought summer was here when the water vapor content went up around the camp."

The oxygen berries:

> Before they could shut it they heard a whistling, like a teakettle coming to boil, then a rapid series of clangs. A tiny white ball came through the doorway and bounced off three walls. It moved almost faster than they could follow. It hit Crawford on the arm, then fell to the floor where it gradually skittered to a stop. The hissing died away, and Crawford picked it up. It was lighter than it had been. There was a pinhole drilled in one side. The pinhole was cold when he touched it with his fingers. Startled, thinking he was burned, he stuck
> his finger in his mouth, then sucked on it absently long after he knew the truth.
>
> "These 'fruit' are full of compressed gas," he told them. "We have to open up another, carefully this time. I'm almost afraid to say what gas I think it is, but I have a hunch that our problems are solved."

Second expedition delayed by strife on Earth:

> By the time the rescue expedition arrived, no one was calling it that. There had been the little matter of a long, brutal war with the Palestinian Empire, and a
> growing conviction that the survivors of the First Expedition had not had any chance in the first place.
> There had been no time for luxuries like space travel beyond the moon and no billions of dollars to invest
> while the world's energy policies were being debated in the Arabian Desert with tactical nuclear weapons.

Waiting for the Martians:

> "We *like* it here. It’s a good place to raise a family, not like Earth the last time I was there. And it couldn't be much better now, right after another war. And we can't leave, even if we wanted to." She flashed him a dazzling smile and patted the ground again.
>
> "The Martians should be showing up any time now. And we aim to thank them."

Comment: Oi, this is _embarrassing_.  I have _three_ of those collections and I _still_ didn't remember it was Varley.  Thank you so much!